# Can an amended bankruptcy schedule be submitted before getting a case number, or is it better to wait?

Tags: united-states, bankruptcy, process

I filed pro se recently (in the US), and I feel pretty good and confident about my petition. I did notice though I made a minor mistake on one page with some amounts—nothing major and it isn't a big modification, it won't affect anything, but I still want to be as correct as possible.

Can one submit the amended schedule ASAP, or is it necessary/good practice to wait until a case number is assigned?

Comment: So much of this comes down to local practice rules and customs at this level of granularity that I do not believe that it would be helpful to provide a general answer to this question. If in doubt call the clerk of the bankruptcy court or the efiling help line.